# 500 Internal error when posting data to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, httprequest

trying to POST data to a php file using ajax.

I am facing a 500 internal error.

However when I check using the developer options available in chrome, the post URL is perfect and so is the POST data.

I am using the following to print any post data

```
 <?php 
print_r($_POST);
```

But nothing turns up on the screen.

I believe if the error is due to invalid fields, at least some post data should be printed at the beginning of the php program.

Lost here, I picked up php today and am confused where to start on debugging too.

here is my ajax call:

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'page/pagename.php',   
                    data: $('#general').serialize(),
                    success: function(html) {...}});
```

Comment: Look at your logs and enable error reporting. This is a server error.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network also to see exactly what is being sent

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner hi , this all the log says, any pointers?`03:11:01 15-11-2018, IP:localhost, User: admin, Message: ajax save`

Comment: @charlietfl hi, inspected using dev tool, the post data and url are perfect, lost!!

Comment: Check your php script code, if error does not display on browser then add these lines  at start of php script: ini_set('display_errors', 1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @LoveBuddha You are a gem
I am now able to catch errors in the code
Thanks

Comment: @Prashanth Love you.. _/\_